# Remove Underscore and text in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Is there a way that I can remove text with an underscore in **python**!.
Let say I have the following sentence:
I ate an apple today stay_healthy_eat_well
I want to remove: "stay_healthy_eat_well"

Comment: Use the replace method? `sentnece.replace("_", " ")`

Comment: What is the `pandas` aspect of this? Is this a _column_ of values?

Comment: is it going to remove the whole sentence "stay_healthy_eat_well" or just the underscore sign? @Goion

Comment: So, you want to remove any word that CONTAINS an underscore?

Comment: it is a dataset of tweets @HenryEcker

Comment: yes @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence = "I ate an apple today stay_healthy_eat_well"

def filter_string(str):
    a = []
    for i in str.split():
        if "_" not in i:
            a.append(i)
    return ' '.join(a)
print(filter_string(sentence))
```

**result:** I ate an apple today

All the above code can be written in single line.

```
print(" ".join([word for word in sentence.split() if "_" not in word]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use str.replace() method:

```
strtest = "I ate an apple today stay_healthy_eat_well"
print(strtest.replace("_", " "))  # Swaps '_' for space
```

--
But if you want to remove all the words connected to the underlines:

```
strtest = "I ate an apple today stay_healthy_eat_well"
split_list = strtest.split(" ")  # Create a list, splitting by space
var_list = [x for x in split_list if "_" not in x]  # new list without '_'
print(var_list)
```